# Does BLE bonding encrypt all communication?

Tags: encryption, bluetooth-lowenergy

We have some characteristics that are marked bonded/encrypted and some that are unbonded.  Obviously if we have two unbonded devices, communication over the unbonded characteristics will not be encrypted, but does that change once bonding has occurred?  Once the two devices are bonded, are all communications encrypted (even those over unbonded characteristics)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole link is either encrypted or not so either all data is encrypted or none.

When a Bluetooth stack supports "marking" a characteristic with a specific security level and the link does not currently meet the required security, it will try to take the required actions to make the link meet the required security level and then try again. That means either start encryption if the devices are already bonded, or initiate pairing.

Note that even if two devices are bonded and posses a shared encryption key, that doesn't necessarily mean that the link will automatically be encrypted when a connection starts since it's not mandatory to encrypt the link.